# appx in CLRCORE meaning Windows Store AppX?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, clr, coreclr

The Appx mentioned in the following URL is referring to Windows Store AppX?
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/vm/appxutil.h

Comment: Yes, more obvious from appxutil.cpp.  ICoreApplication is a Store (aka WinRT, aka UWP) interface.  RoInitialize() must be called instead of CoInitialize() to initialize COM.  An ApplicationID is a WinRT app property, visible on the appx manifest editor.  The code is part of the language projection built into the CLR to map WinRT types to .NET types, lots more code is involved.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from  Hans, please refer to it .